# OpenGL ES shader compilation

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, shader

I am trying to create applications with opengl. Debugging on a real device.
I create the context like this::

```
GLSurfaceView baseView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
baseView.setEGLContextClientVersion(3);
baseView.setRenderer(new GameView());
```

I compile shaders like this:

```
    int program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    int idShad = (type == 0) ? GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER : GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER;

    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(idShad);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, source);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

    int[] isCompiled = new int[1];
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, isCompiled, 0);
    if (isCompiled[0] == GL_FALSE) {
        String infoLog = "";
        infoLog = glGetShaderInfoLog(shader);
        glDeleteShader(shader);

        String typeShader = (type == 0) ? "Vertex Shader" : "Fragment Shader";
        Log.e("OpenGl", "Cannot compile " + typeShader + ": " + infoLog);
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    glAttachShader(program, shader);
```

But I always getting this error:

> Cannot compile: Vertex Shader: 0:3: L0001: Typename expected, found '�'

I get it when loading from a file and when creating a line in the code
For any code, even an empty shader, here are examples:

```
    public static final String baseMatrixVX = 
        "#version 300 es\n"
        + "void main() {\n"
        + "}\0";

        public static final String texMatrixVX =
        "#version 330\n"
        + "layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;\n"
        + "layout(location = 1) in vec3 color;\n"
        + "layout(location = 2) in vec2 tex;\n"
        + "out vec3 colorOut;\n"
        + "out vec2 texOut;\n"
        + "uniform bool enabledCam;\n"
        + "uniform mat4 projection;\n"
        + "uniform mat4 cam;\n"
        + "uniform mat4 model;\n"
        + "void main() {\n"
        + "if (enabledCam) {\n"
        + "    gl_Position = projection * model * cam * vec4(pos, 1.0f);\n"
        + "} else {\n"
        + "    gl_Position = projection * model * vec4(pos, 1.0f);\n"
        + "}\n"
        + "colorOut = vec3(color);\n"
        + "texOut = tex;\n"
        + "}\0";
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S device supports opengle es 3 and above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem is in the last character \0.
Should be used instead \n